# installed patsy, still can't install statsmodels

Tags: python, pip, statsmodels

When I do `pip install statsmodels` it gives me `ImportError: statsmodels requires patsy. http://patsy.readthedocs.org`, but then I run `pip install patsy` and it says its successful, but running `pip install statsmodels` still gives me same error about requiring patsy.

How can this be?

---

```
$ sudo pip install patsy
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): patsy in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/patsy-0.3.0-py2.7.egg
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.8.2-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg (from patsy)
Cleaning up...
$ sudo pip install statsmodels
Downloading/unpacking statsmodels
  Downloading statsmodels-0.5.0.tar.gz (5.5MB): 5.5MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/tmp/pip_build_root/statsmodels/setup.py) egg_info for package statsmodels
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/statsmodels/setup.py", line 463, in <module>
        check_dependency_versions(min_versions)
      File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/statsmodels/setup.py", line 122, in check_dependency_versions
        raise ImportError("statsmodels requires patsy. http://patsy.readthedocs.org")
    ImportError: statsmodels requires patsy. http://patsy.readthedocs.org
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/statsmodels/setup.py", line 463, in <module>

    check_dependency_versions(min_versions)

  File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/statsmodels/setup.py", line 122, in check_dependency_versions

    raise ImportError("statsmodels requires patsy. http://patsy.readthedocs.org")

ImportError: statsmodels requires patsy. http://patsy.readthedocs.org

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip_build_root/statsmodels
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/Jacob/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

Comment: Does the basic patsy stuff on the docs work? in other words, did patsy really install properly? Maybe try the --upgrade to the latest...

Comment: Ah, it was because I didn't have `six`.

Comment: Try running `python -c 'from patsy import __version__'` and let us know the output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What the error message doesn't tell you is that the module `six` not being there is really the problem.

Found this out by doing `import patsy` and having it fail and tell me that I needed `six`. So I did `pip install six` and now the patsy import worked, as did the `pip install statsmodels`.

Comment: this didn't help me. statsmodels still failed to install

Answer (score 1):

For me:

```
$python3 -m pip install --upgrade patsy
$python3 -m pip install statsmodels
```

worked!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still experiencing issues, I highly recommend this site:
[Python libraries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#statsmodels). I'm using Python 3, so I,

1. Downloaded the file named: `statsmodels‑0.8.0‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl`
2. Opened windows command prompt
3. Went to my Downloads directory (`cd Downloads`)
4. And then used pip (`pip install statsmodels‑0.8.0‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl`)

Answer (score 0):

I also had an issue with this in Python 3.4. It worked using the WHL statsmodel file at this link: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/statsmodels#downloads

After the download I installed it using: pip3.4 install my_directory\statsmodels-0.8.0rc1-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl, where my_directory is where I put the WHL file.